# works on bootstrap and not works

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me with a code inside bootstrap (html and css)???
In bootstrap Documentation i try to get dropdown menu (burger menu) but it wont let me expand the burger menu (Dropdown)

I have try it on Firefox and Google Chrome

I have some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Demo BootStrap</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Demo</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Desk</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Create</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i need help to, is to expand the bruger menu and dropdown menu.

Thank you !

Best Reagrds
Frederik / 007fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Data-Toggle to Data-Bs-Toggle,
Change Data-Target to Data-Bs-Target.

```
<button
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
  data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
```